# function execution using jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I looking for a code where, I have defined same function name as assigned class name. I need to execute function when I click on that link.

Is this possible?

Comment: need code please - with no context it is hard to understand your question

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have this markup:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">test</a>
```

and this JS:

```
function foo() { ... }
```

and you want to call that function when the link is clicked, try something like:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window[$(this).attr("class")]();
});
```

That takes advantage of the fact that global-level functions are automatically a property of the `window` object, and assumes you want this behaviour for *all* links (modify the initial jQuery selector, as appropriate, if that's not the case).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make of your question, inside of the DOM ready, place:

```
$(".class-name").click(function(event) {
    functionNameHere();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what jQuery's `click` is for:

```
$(".myClass").click(myFunction);
```